# Is THRUST stable_sort_by_key O(n)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda, thrust

Can I assume that Thrust `stable_sort_by_key` performed on `unsigned int` has complexity `O(n)`? If not what should I do to be sure that this complexity will be achieved? (Except of implementing radix sort on my own)

Comment: You can directly use [`cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html). CUB is used in the backend by Thrust, but I don't see the guarantee you want in the docs, so even if it uses the right thing, that would be an implementation detail that I wouldn't base my code on.

Comment: That being said, from looking at [those implementation details](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/772c0f4870201b971da1db9cf7b698e2715cb440/thrust/system/cuda/detail/sort.h#L410-L485) Thrust is able to figure out if it can use a radix sort and will use it when appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit on your circumstances/view. Just from the docs/API there doesn't seem to be a guarantee for `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` on `unsigned int` keys using a radix sort.

On the other hand the necessary algorithm [`cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs`](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_radix_sort.html#a65e82152de448c6373ed9563aaf8af7e) is implemented in the CUB library which is used by Thrust in the backend and there is no good reason for Thrust not to use it as the prerequisites can easily be queried at compile time.

From the code in `thrust/system/cuda/detail/sort.h`(the "detail" should warn you that this is not part of the public API) one can see that `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` can launch a `cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs` under the right circumstances (arithmetic key type and using `thrust::less` or `thrust::greater` as comparison operation) at least on the [main branch of Thrust at the time of writing](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/blob/772c0f4870201b971da1db9cf7b698e2715cb440/thrust/system/cuda/detail/sort.h) (ca. v2.0.0rc2) but probably for a long time already. Else it will fall back to a merge sort.

Directly using `cub::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs` could have benefits even if this is enough for you, as this makes it easier to reuse temporary buffers and avoid unnecessary synchronization. Both can be done in Thrust via a

```cpp
auto exec = thrust::cuda::par_nosync(custom_allocator).on(custom_stream);
```

execution policy (the most recent CUDA Toolkit 11.8 still comes with old Thrust v1.15 without v1.16 `par_nosync`). One thing that can not be avoided using Thrust is the in-place nature of the sorting algorithms which is achieved by potentially copying the results back to the input buffers. These copy operations can only be elided using CUB.

Comment: So just to clarify
I can sort type `T` by key `unsigned int` with complexity `O(n)` using only default `stable_sort_by_key` from thrust api? I understand that there is no guarantee that it will use radix sort in the future.

Comment: As far as I understand the source, it should call a radix sort. You could check in a profiler, i.e. nSight Systems, to make sure. In a massively parallel environment O-notation can be even more missleading than it is already. The only good reason I could imagine for Thrust to not use the radix sort in the future is that something else is faster in practice on the given hardware (not necessarily better O).